# Would it be possible to multiply a Matrix with an initializer_list?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to make a Math library and am wondering if it would be possible to multiply a matrix by an uninitialised_list straight away instead of wrapping it in a vector first.

I want to obtain something like this.

```
 Matrix<double> M = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
 vector<double> v = M * {2.0, 2.0};
```

The matrix initialisation works perfectly fine. So Matrix M is a 2x2 matrix. I want to multiply this M by the vector {2.0, 2.0} however I am getting the follow error.

```
error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
     vector<double> v = M * {2.0, 2.0};
```

My question is would this actually be possible in c++?

My overloaded operator * which would accept an initializer_list is below.

```
template<typename T>
vector<T> Matrix<T>::operator*(const initializer_list<T> &list)
{
  vector<T> result(list.size(), 0.0);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < d_rows; ++i) 
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < d_cols; ++j) 
    {
      result[i] = d_matrix[i][j] * *(list + j);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I think it's not allowed syntactically. `M.operator*({2.0, 2.0})` should work, however.

Comment: Exactly, however that wouldn't be intuitive...

Comment: Alternatively, `using ili = std::initializer_list<int>; auto v = M * ili{2.0, 2.0};` (or via deduction of `int`, `auto v = M * deduce({2.0, 2.0});`)

Answer (score 0):

An initializer should be used for initializing. I don't way it's not possible but there're some workarounds:

```
vector<T> Matrix<T>::operator*(std::initializer_list<double> a)
{
    ....
}

auto v = M * std::initializer_list<double>{2.0, 2.0};
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            //  Make an initialized object
```

However it's not suitable and readable enough. I prefer something like belowcode:

```
auto v = M * Matrix<double>{2.0, 2.0};
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               // Initialized Matrix
```

Comment: You forgot the brackets.   `auto v = M * std::initializer_list<double>({2.0, 2.0});` works perfectly fine

Comment: BTW: Having a matrix operator *= taking an initializer_list and returning a (math) vector: v = m *= { 1, 2, 3 } compiles fine (gcc 4.7.2)

Comment: But that would be a strange use of *= right? cuz a matrix mult a vector yields a vector not a matrix